# How to use Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, grouping

I am wondering how is the right way to use enum in java.
I have implemented the following code and it gives an error.

```
public class GlobalVariables {

public enum Algorithm{louvain, kmeans};

public enum Evolution{survive,merge,split,dissolve};

/**
 * GED alpha threshold
 */
public static float GED_INCLUSION_ALPHA = 0.5f;

/**
 * GED beta threshold
 */
public static float GED_INCLUSION_BETA = 0.7f;}
```

Do you know what i am possibly doing wrong?

The error:
Multiple markers at this line

> - louvain cannot be resolved to a type
> - 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source 
>      level 1.5 on
> - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
> - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations
> - enum cannot be resolved to a type
> - enum cannot be resolved to a type
> - 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source 
>      level 1.5 on
> - Syntax error on token ",", delete this token

Comment: Show your error? We don't have a Java compiler built-in in our eyes.

Comment: What kind of error? Please post the error message. Compilation error or runtime error? For runtime error, post the full stack trace.

Comment: Please study [ask] to improve the question. It will help you get an answer and it will help us trying to give you one.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try to use the enums in this class? If so, how are you using them and what is the error?

Comment: [Your code compiles and runs fine](http://ideone.com/tFIeks).

Comment: I don't know how many times I've posted this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html - I suggest bookmarking it!

Comment: Time to upgrade your Java version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code that you have posted here. It is working fine with compiler java version 1.5 and above.
Always remember enum is introduced in java 5, so check your compiler setting in IDE if you are using any or you can check you compiler version from terminal.

java -version

you can check more about enum; how to use enum in java and much more details about it from [Walking Techie](http://walkingtechie.blogspot.com/2017/01/java-enum.html)

Answer (score 5):

This error:

> 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5 on

seems to imply that you are compiling using a source version < 1.5. And enums were introduced in Java 1.5.

Check your compiler or IDE settings.

Alternatively, there may be a syntax error in some code that you haven't shown in your question.

Comment: Thank you (was using a source version < 1.5)

Answer (score -1):

I would see your enum used together with a switch; 
Based on the Algorithm(Type) we select a specific implementation for the Algorithm interface that contains a method: executeAlgorithm, that we can call further down the line.

The following code is compiling and working in Java 1.6 and higher (check your java version cause enums are added in 1.5)

```
public class GlobalVariables {


    interface Algorithm {
        void executeAlgorithm();
    }

    public enum AlgorithmType {louvain, kmeans}

    public enum Evolution {survive, merge, split, dissolve}

    /**
     * GED alpha threshold
     */
    public static float GED_INCLUSION_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    /**
     * GED beta threshold
     */
    public static float GED_INCLUSION_BETA = 0.7f;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlgorithmType algorithmType = AlgorithmType.louvain; //initialize it from somewhere

        Algorithm algorithm = null;
        switch (algorithmType) {
            case louvain: {
                algorithm = new LouvainAlgorithmImplementation();
                break;
            }
            case kmeans: {
                algorithm = new KMeansAlgorithmImplementation();
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // do something for default;
                algorithm = new DefaultAlgorithmImplementation();
            }
        }
        algorithm.executeAlgorithm();
    }

    static class LouvainAlgorithmImplementation implements Algorithm {
        @Override
        public void executeAlgorithm() {
            System.out.println("Louvain was called");
        }
    }

    static class KMeansAlgorithmImplementation implements Algorithm {
        @Override
        public void executeAlgorithm() {
            System.out.println("KMeans was called");

        }
    }

    static class DefaultAlgorithmImplementation implements Algorithm {
        @Override
        public void executeAlgorithm() {
            System.out.println("Default was called");
        }
    }

}
```